# Android. Получить данные из потока

Tags: android, google-maps-api, geocoding

Не получается получить данные из потока, в котором запрашиваю координаты местоположения.

```
public void requestCoordinates(final String input, final ICoordinateReceiver receiver, final boolean updateTimezone) {
    try {
        final String URL = PLACE_API_BASE_URL + "?key="
                + API_KEY + "&address="
                + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8");
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(URL)
                .build();
        Call call = client.newCall(request);
        call.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Request to Google Maps Geocoding API failure");
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                String jsonData = response.body().string();
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonData);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
                    String status = jsonObject.getString("status");
                    if (!status.equals("OK")) {
                        String log = "GoogleMapsGeocoding: url <" + URL + ">  response status <" + status + ">";
                        throw new JSONException(log);
                    }
                    JSONObject jsonGeometry = new JSONObject(jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("geometry"));
                    JSONObject jsonLocation = new JSONObject(jsonGeometry.getString("location"));
                    Coordinate coordinate = new Coordinate();
                    coordinate.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(jsonLocation.getString("lat")));
                    coordinate.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(jsonLocation.getString("lng")));
                    receiver.updatePositionCoordinate(input, coordinate);
                    if (updateTimezone) {
                        GoogleMapsTimezone googleMapsTimezone = new GoogleMapsTimezone();
                        googleMapsTimezone.requestTimezone(input);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    AppUtils.showInfoMessage(MyApplication.getAppContext().getString(R.string.invalid_lang_long_used)).show();
                    if (Fabric.isInitialized()) {
                        Crashlytics.logException(e);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        AppUtils.showInfoMessage(MyApplication.getAppContext().getString(R.string.invalid_lang_long_used)).show();
        Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

Передаю интерфейс по которому необходимо вернуть полученные данные. Разве так нельзя сделать? Что лучше делать в данном случае? AsyncTask?

Реализация интерфейса

```
GoogleMap map;

public void deleteAllMarkers() {
    map.clear();
}

@Override
public void updatePositionCoordinate(String city, Coordinate coordinate) {
    deleteAllMarkers();
    setNewMarker(coordinate, city);
    setCameraPosition(coordinate, getDefaultZoom(), 0, 0);
}
```

Ошибка:

```
06-13 00:32:14.879 15370-15749/com.khasang.forecast 
E/UncaughtException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on the main thread
                                                                         at maps.f.g.b(Unknown Source)
                                                                         at maps.z.D.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                         at maps.ag.t.e(Unknown Source)
                                                                         at uz.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:205)
                                                                         at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IGoogleMapDelegate$zza$zza.clear(Unknown Source)
                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.clear(Unknown Source)
                                                                         at com.khasang.forecast.Maps.deleteAllMarkers(Maps.java:126)
                                                                         at com.khasang.forecast.Maps.updatePositionCoordinate(Maps.java:192)
                                                                         at com.khasang.forecast.api.GoogleMapsGeocoding$1.onResponse(GoogleMapsGeocoding.java:68)
                                                                         at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$AsyncCall.execute(Call.java:168)
```

Answer (score 1):

Согласно ошибке вам надо бы этот метод (метод интерфейса) вызывать в основном потоке приложения. Попробуйте передать Activity в ваш запрос (или скастовать переменную-ссылку на интерфейс к активити, если реализация в активити), вызвать его метод `runOnUiThread()` и уже в нём вызвать ваш метод, на коем падение.